# how to create a new variable according to others and to a time interval (in R)

Tags: r, events, variable-assignment, intervals

I need to assign different values to independent observations based on membership in a group of variables and a time interval of 5 minutes.
As example of my data frame:

```
Fecha <- c(rep("22-05-2019", 9), rep("23-05-2019", 10), rep("24-05-2019", 3))
Noche <- c(rep(1,9), rep(2,13))
Parcela <- c(rep("CH1", 9), rep("CC1", 13))
Camara <- c(rep(2, 18), rep(3, 4))
Tratamiento <- c(rep("CHUNCHO", 9), rep("CONCON", 13))
Hora <- c("20:07", "20:10", "20:15", "23:19", "23:20", "23:22", "23:25", "23:43", "23:44", "22:10", "22:12", "22:13", "22:18", "22:39", "23:12", "23:29", "23:33", "23:43", "23:59", "0:21", "0:22", "1:20")
Especie <- c(rep("OL", 3), rep("AX", 4), rep("RR", 2), rep("AX", 5), rep("RR", 8))

datos <- data.frame(Fecha, Noche, Parcela, Camara, Tratamiento, Hora, Especie)
datos

 #  Fecha       Noche   Parcela Camara  Tratamiento  Hora    Especie
 1  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      20:07   OL
 2  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      20:10   OL
 3  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      20:15   OL
 4  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:19   AX
 5  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:20   AX
 6  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:22   AX
 7  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:25   AX
 8  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:43   RR
 9  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:44   RR
10  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:10   AX
11  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:12   AX
12  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:13   AX
13  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:18   AX
14  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:39   AX
15  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       23:12   RR
16  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       23:29   RR
17  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       23:33   RR
18  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       23:43   RR
19  23-05-2019  2       CC1     3       CONCON       23:59   RR
20  24-05-2019  2       CC1     3       CONCON       0:21    RR
21  24-05-2019  2       CC1     3       CONCON       0:22    RR
22  24-05-2019  2       CC1     3       CONCON       1:20    RR
```

This would be with events asigned:

```
    #  Fecha       Noche   Parcela Camara  Tratamiento  Hora    Especie   Group Event
    1  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      20:07   OL        AA     1
    2  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      20:10   OL        AA     1
    3  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      20:15   OL        AA     2
    4  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:19   AX        AB     3
    5  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:20   AX        AB     3 
    6  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:22   AX        AB     3
    7  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:25   AX        AB     4 
    8  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:43   RR        AC     5 
    9  22-05-2019  1       CH1     2       CHUNCHO      23:44   RR        AC     5
   10  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:10   AX        AD     6
   11  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:12   AX        AD     6
   12  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:13   AX        AD     6
   13  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:18   AX        AD     7
   14  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       22:39   AX        AD     8
   15  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       23:12   RR        AE     9
   16  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       23:29   RR        AE    10
   17  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       23:33   RR        AE    10
   18  23-05-2019  2       CC1     2       CONCON       23:43   RR        AE    11 
   19  23-05-2019  2       CC1     3       CONCON       23:59   RR        AF    12 
   20  24-05-2019  2       CC1     3       CONCON       0:21    RR        AF    13
   21  24-05-2019  2       CC1     3       CONCON       0:22    RR        AF    13
   22  24-05-2019  2       CC1     3       CONCON       1:20    RR        AF    14
```

"Event" would be a new variable where its values or labels (it can be a number, letters, symbols, whatever) differ between groups (provided by Noche, Parcela, Camara, Tratamiento and Especie) and within groups if there are more than 5 minutes between them. The interval starts would be set to some early observations, so it would not be the difference of 5 minutes for all subsequent observations.
The column "Group" is not needed, I put it just to clarify groups and it would be useful in case a solution provided unique events only for each group.

The solution provided by Ronak Shah is very close:

```
library(dplyr)

    datos %>%
      tidyr::unite(datetime, Fecha, Hora, sep = ' ') %>%
      mutate(datetime = dmy_hm(datetime)) %>%
      group_by(Parcela, Camara, Tratamiento, Especie) %>%
      mutate(grp = cut(datetime, breaks = '5 mins')) %>%
      group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>%
      mutate(Event = cur_group_id())
```

, but with it there´s still some error. In the example, Rows #16 and #17 should be in the same event, but with this method appear apart

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to divide data for every 5 mins for each value of `Plot`, `Treatment` , `Camera` and `Species`. Using `cur_group_id` we generate a unique id in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

datos %>%
  tidyr::unite(datetime, Fecha, Hora, sep = ' ') %>%
  mutate(datetime = dmy_hm(datetime)) %>%
  group_by(Parcela, Camara, Tratamiento, Especie) %>%
  mutate(grp = cut(datetime, breaks = '5 mins')) %>%
  group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Event = cur_group_id()) -> result

result
```

Comment: Thanks but when I run it shows this:
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `grp`.
x 'to' must be a finite number
i Input `grp` is `cut(Date_Time, breaks = "5 mins")`.
i The error occurred in group 1: plot = "A", Treatment = "FOX", Camera = 1, Species = "AX".

Comment: @RodrigoSalgadoMoya Please add sample of your data in a reproducible format for us to debug. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: On "datos" of my answer below, I made this:

`datos$fechahora <- as.POSIXct(paste(datos$Fecha, datos$Hora), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
datos$group_id <- datos %>% group_by(Noche, Parcela, Camara, Tratamiento, Especie) %>%
  group_indices()

datos <- datos %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(grp = cut(fechahora, breaks = '5 mins')) %>%
  group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Event = cur_group_id())`

But still have an error at event assignment in #17

Comment: @RodrigoSalgadoMoya See if the updated answer helps.

Comment: Thanks. It was really close. I thought  It was it but I found some errors and i dont know why, I dont see a pattern. .
For example: within a group,  
time (event):  1:49:00 (17), 2:21:00 (18), 2:23:00 (19), 2:25:00 (19), 2:26:00 (19)

Answer (score 0):

If your data can be arranged/sorted by the columns Plot, Treatment, Camera and Species then you can save yourself the iteration part to estimate the group flag and use dplyr::group_indices function instead.

Here is my solution:

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)

# Load data
plot <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4))
Treatment <- c(rep("FOX", 5), rep("EAGLE", 3))
Camera <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,2), 1)
Species <- c(rep("AX", 3), "RR", rep("AX", 4))
date1 <- rep("2020-05-01", 8)
date2 <- c("20:20", "20:22", "20:26", "20:23", "20:20", "20:21", "20:23", "20:23")
Date_Time <- as.POSIXct(paste(date1, date2)) 
df <- data.frame(plot, Treatment, Camera, Species, Date_Time)

# Get count vector for each group and a 5 minutes change flag
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(plot, Treatment, Camera, Species) %>%
  mutate(count = 1:n(),
         time_change = ifelse(as.numeric(Date_Time - first(Date_Time)) / 60 < 5, 0, 1))
# Adjust the group flag to have a continuos one
count <- df$count
groups <- c(0, nrow(df))
for (k in 1:length(count)) {
  delta <- count[k] - count[k-1]
  if (k == 1) {
    groups[k] <- 1
  } else if (delta > 0) {
    groups[k] <- groups[k-1]
  } else {
    groups[k] <- groups[k-1] + 1
  }
}
# Get final event flag
df$Event <- groups + cumsum(df$time_change) 
df <- subset(df, select = -c(count, time_change))
```

Comment: Thank you. I can run it with your propose, but only in this data that I made as example, not in my real data. I dont know why. Maybe it is cause the format of time data which date and time were separated and as characters at first, although I used "as.POSIXct(paste(date, time))" as you did. I see one problem is establishing a flag or a cut when an event ends and starts another because is not only given by the first cell of each group

Comment: I can't help you if I can't have at least a sample of your real data. The solution posted works with the example you have provided.